# Name of fixed-point/integer representation with alternate unit of measurement

Tags: floating-point, integer, units-of-measurement, fixed-point, representation

When processing signals and sensor values in embedded C, we can usually choose between representing the values in floating-point (e.g. [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)) or fixed-point, the latter often preferred when no floating-point unit is available, as it's my case.

I was wondering what is the name of a solution/pattern where we use just plain integers to represent the sensor value without decimals because we simply change the unit of measurement the value is represented in the unit of the maximum accuracy.

#### Example

Let's assume I have a distance-measuring sensor (like a proximity sensor) with millimetre-accuracy. An example output would be `1.234 m`. I have the following choices to store the output distance measurement:

1. *floating-point*, representing the distance in metres
2. *fixed-point*, representing the distance in metres, with 3 decimal places for the millimetres
3. *integer*, representing the distance in **millimetres** instead of metres

I only need to take care of having large-enough integers when doing arithmetics with the third option to avoid overflows. For example: computing the area of a rectangle measured by two sensors is done by multiplying two distances in millimetres `a*b` and this requires twice as many bits, because the unit is also squared: `mm^2`.

#### Non-SI cases

The same "third option" representation can be used for more complex stuff than just SI-prefixes, like a `int32_t` representing `k` multiples of `sqrt(2)` instead of saving `k*sqrt(2)` into a float directly, that is: storing `int32_t k_foo = 3;` instead of `float foo = 4.2426405f;`.

#### My question

Is there an official name for the "third option" in data representation? It's like fixed-point with no decimal places but with a non-standard unit. The "decimal places" are implicit in the used measurements unit. I have a hard time documenting this (kind of stupid) solution without a name.

Comment: When using SI units with metric prefixes, how is that different from decimal fixed-point?

Comment: The difference is that metric prefixes need to be indicated across the data types or variable names and can be operated on (+, -, *, /) directly instead of using a fixed-point API function call - e.g. sum of numbers in [Q number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)). Both use integers behind the scenes.

Comment: It is not clear what distinction you are making between fixed-point and integer with different units. If I store the distance 1.234 m in `x` using fixed-point with a scale of 10^3, then `x` contains 1234. if I store the distance 1234 mm in `x` as an integer, then `x` contains 1234. If I have some distance 4.321 stored in `y` in the same way (4321 in `y`), and I multiply them with an integer multiply operation, then the product is 5,332,114 regardless of whether I regard `x` and `y` as fixed-point meters or integer millimeters.

Comment: In any case, if you want a name, you can simply call it “scaled.”

Comment: You might consider reading the NIST [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf). Although it largely covers editorial style for technical documents, it has insights about what unit notations mean. For example, we cannot store a physical quantity in a variable `x`; we can only store a number. So, if we have some length L, we should not say `x` contains L but rather `x` contains L/mm. That is, if we divide a length, say 12 inches, by one millimeter, we get a number, 304.8. Then `x` may contain this pure number, a unitless quantity.

Comment: What I mean by fixed-point is a binary representation of a real number where _m_ bits are dedicated to the whole part and _n_ bits are dedicated to the fractional part. So for a distance in meters a representation in Q5.10 (TI-notation) would have 1 sign bit, 5 integer-part bits [0, 31] and 10 fractional-part bits [0, 1023], thus representing a range of [-32.023, 32.023] meters. In some languages (like SQL) this is also possible in base-10, indicating the decimal places after the comma.

Comment: Yes, I know what fixed-point is. The question is what distinction you are making between fixed-point with one unit and integer with a different unit. They both result in exactly the same bit settings being used. In what way are they not isomorphic?

Comment: Sorry, I misundertood. The distinction is exactly the point of my question: are they distinct? Is one a special case of the other? (I would say so). And more importantly, does this special case/design pattern have a name? I would like to avoid calling it "fixed-point" which makes the reader think of a decimal-separator and decimal-places when there are none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed-point representations are scaled representations and vice-versa. From [the Wikipedia page on fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic):

> A fixed-point representation of a fractional number is essentially an integer that is to be implicitly multiplied by a fixed scaling factor. For example, the value 1.23 can be stored in a variable as the integer value 1230 with implicit scaling factor of 1/1000 (meaning that the last 3 decimal digits are implicitly assumed to be a decimal fraction), and the value 1 230 000 can be represented as 1230 with an implicit scaling factor of 1000 (with "minus 3" implied decimal fraction digits, that is, with 3 implicit zero digits at right).

The web page even gives an example of using a change of units as the scaling factor:

> However, other scaling factors may be used occasionally, e.g. a fractional amount of hours may be represented as an integer number of seconds; that is, as a fixed-point number with scale factor of 1/3600.

The term “fixed-point” arises because it is common to represent a number using an integer in some fixed base, such as binary or decimal, and say that the number represented is the one obtained by putting a decimal point (or binary point or radix point) at a fixed place in the number. For example:

- The binary numeral 110101<sub>2</sub> may represent 110.101<sub>2</sub> in a fixed-point format with three binary digits after the radix point. This is equivalent to scaling by 2<sup>3</sup>.
- The decimal numeral 1234 may represent 12.34 in a fixed-point format with three decimal digits after the radix point. This is equivalent to scaling by 10<sup>2</sup>.

Generally, a fixed-point format represents a number *x* as *x*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *b* and *e* are fixed. A scaled format represents a number *x* as *x*•*S*, where *S* is fixed. **These two are equivalent.** Any fixed-point format *x*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> is the scaled format *x*•*S* where *S* = *b*<sup>*e*</sup>, and any scaled format *x*•*S* is the fixed-point format *x*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> where *b* = *S* and *e* = 1.

Integer representations are a trivial subset of fixed-point representations where *e* = 0.

One distinction of fixed-point formats and scaled formats arises in the ease of implementation using arithmetic in the base *b*. Normally, implementing multiplication and division requires multiplying and dividing by the scale. Given *x* and *y* with representations *x*' = *x*•*S* and *y*' = *y*•*S*:

- Addition is implemented by adding representations: (*x*+*y*)' = *x*' + *y*'.
- Subtraction is implemented by subtracting representations: (*x*−*y*)' = *x*' − *y*'.
- Multiplication is implemented by multiplying and compensating for the scale: (*x*•*y*)' = *x*'•*y*' / *S*.
- Division is implemented similarly: (*x*/*y*)' = *x*'•*S*/*y*'.

Multiplication requires time and energy, and division more so. If a fixed-point representation is used with *b* equal to the base used to represent the integers, then the multiplications and divisions can be replaced by shifts. Thus, it is advantageous to choose a fixed-point format with *b* equal to the base used to represent integers. Equivalently, it is advantageous to choose a scaled format with *S* equal to a power of the base used to represent integers.

Thus, there is no mathematical difference between fixed-point and scaled representations, and there is little, if any, semantic difference. Either way, the choice of scaling factor is a matter of practical concern involving ease of computation and satisfactory precision, not whether the format is called fixed-point or scaled.